# Fancybox IFRAME Form onsubmit

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I am working on a database search and when the use clicks submit I wanted it to open a iframe in a fancybox, which I have working but it quickly redirects to a new page, here is my code, hope someone can help :)

```
<script>
$("#submitform").fancybox({
    type : "iframe",
    href : "http://...."
});
</script>
```

Comment: It depends on what search engine you are using; some may not allow to be opened inside an iframe because they may have an [x-frame-options response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options)